# Is the id irreplaceable or not?

Tags: mysql, database-design, xampp, auto-increment

I searched nothing on the google when I typed this. In the xampp server, if I make an ***ID*** table(also it is in ***INT***), for example, User ***A*** created an account and it's ***ID*** is ***12***. Then, user ***A*** deleted it's account, so it's ***ID(12)*** also deleted. Now my question is if another user created an account, will be the ***ID*** of new ***USER*** is ***12*** or it will automatically looped and go to ***ID 13*** ?

Comment: If it's a MySQL table and it has `AUTO-INCREMENT` set to `true` then it will never enter the same number twice, regardless of what is currently in the table. You can reset this but need to run specific commands on this table in MySQL,

Comment: @Martin 's comments are not totally correct.  Let's rephrase it.  At any given time no two rows will have the same number.  However, if you delete #12 _and_ it is the highest ID, then restart MySQL, #12 _may_ be reused.

Comment: @rick james, in more normal way, if one's website is consistently running, and one of the users account deleted ? then it will replaced or not ?

Comment: #12 will be reused in InnoDB, not in MyISAM.  If you need a guarantee that the number 12 to never be reused, you need a mechanism other than `AUTO_INCREMENT`.  If, when deleting the user, you deleted all references to #12 in other tables; does it really matter that 12 was reused?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your database structure.

Usually, the best thing is to use an auto increment primary key for your `ID` column. That way, MySQL assigns the next value automatically. It always increments, never going back to fill in missing values -- because that could destroy the integrity of your tables.

Say your users are associated with forum posts, and user **A** removes their account, which removes their entry from your users table but not the forum post itself<sup>1</sup>, which still references user ID 12. If you were to force the re-use of old values, a new user would then be associated with the previous user's posts.

This causes some people hardship if they try to use the auto increment column for some other purpose (sorting order, or as a count in a loop in their application), but that's generally misuse of the column and usually means they're doing it wrong (and should either add another column or use a different method of counting).

1 - Note that I wouldn't actually build my forum software this way, but it's a decent illustration of the point.

Comment: If you delete user #12, you had better delete all the rows in the other tables that reference #12.